# Broadcast message to clients using RMI

Tags: java, rmi

Can anyone please explain how to implement broadcasting of a message from the server to clients using Java RMI?

I basically want to send a message from the server to all clients.

Comment: First question - Why to implement this using RMI? Why not using plain Java Socket Multicasting? If this is the only thing you want to achieve, you're looking at a complex, outdated technology (RMI).

Comment: It's an assignment given to us hence the question. I know it's an outdated technology but I need to understand it either way. @Am_I_Helpful

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful This 'outdated technology' is at the heart of every J2EE deployment on the planet.

Comment: @EJP - And, you should agree that all the legacy enterprise applications (using J2EE) are way behind, when compared to smarter things like REST, etc. on this planet! Enterprise takes time to move on, as I myself work in an enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

1. The clients needs to export a remote object that is used for callbacks.
2. Each client needs to register its callback with the server.
3. The server needs to maintain a collection of these callbacks.
4. The server needs to iterator over the collection calling each callback.

It's a poor assignment. Quite inappropriate.

- It isn't obvious how to do it.
- The server doesn't have a well-defined time to remove a callback from the collection. The client could unregister its callback, but there is no guarantee that it really will before exiting.
- It will not work at all in the presence of client side firewalls.
- RMI is a unicast technology, not a broadcast technology.
- RMI is not well suited to callback architectures.